# Error in grails 2.3.7 app while running and cleaning

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-2.3

I have cloned an app from git,  *grails-clean* command was giving the below errors

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-core;7.0.52: not found

:: org.apache.tomcat#tomcat-catalina-ant;7.0.52: not found

:: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-jasper;7.0.52: not found

:: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-logging-log4j;7.0.52: no

:: org.apache.tomcat.embed#tomcat-embed-websocket;7.0.52: not fo

:: org.zkoss.zk#zk;7.0.1: not found

:: org.zkoss.zk#zkplus;7.0.1: not found

:: org.grails.plugins#zk;2.4.0: not found

:: com.ibm.icu#icu4j;4.8.1.1: not found

:: commons-pool#commons-pool;1.5.4: not found

:: org.grails.plugins#functional-test;2.0.0: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I have changed tomcat-dependency to below in buildConfig.groovy

**build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"**

After this, the app is not even responding on *grails-clean*, No lines gets printed in the console, except “Configuring classpath”

So, I have created a **grails 2.3.7 sample app**, When I run it, I got the error as below:

| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor
for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due
to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repos
itories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration
to continue.

I have grails 2.2.1, There are no issues with the apps in this versions

**OS: Windows 8
   , Java version: 1.6.0_81**

Comment: Are you behind proxy?

Comment: Do you had any other grails versions before?

Comment: Yes, I have grails 2.2.1 version installed as well

Comment: Check your connection and check if the repos inside buildConfig.groovy are in place.  http://pastebin.com/xZfp3Pif

Comment: You are right, There was Network issue